# Atom Compiler for C++ gives me wrong output for converting a value to binary

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, binary, atom-editor

So I have written a code for printing first 20 Binary Numbers like
0
1
10
11
100
101 and so on...

I Tried running the code in Atom Editor it's not accurate but when I ran the same code in an Online compiler it gave me a correct answer which I expected

This is the code that I used :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

 int toBinary(int num){
   int ans = 0;
   int i = 0;
   while(num!=0){
     int bit = num&1;
     ans = ( bit * pow(10,i) ) + ans;

     num = num>>1;
     i++;

   }
   return ans;
 }

int main(){

  for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
    cout<<toBinary(i)<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is the output i'm getting in ATOM editor:

```
0 1 10 11 99 100 109 110 1000 1001 1010 1011 1099 1100 1109 1110 9999 10000 10009 10010
```

And this is the output I'm getting in Online Compiler (this is the output I expect):

```
0 1 10 11 100 101 110 111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111 10000 10001 10010 10011
```

Comment: You should explain exactly what you get in your environment (and how it differs from what you expect). Anyway - you shouldn't use `pow` for integers.

Comment: This is the output i'm getting in ATOM editor - 
0
1
10
11
99
100
109
110
1000
1001
1010
1011
1099
1100
1109
1110
9999
10000
10009
10010

And this is the output I'm getting in Online Compiler - 
0
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
10000
10001
10010
10011
@wohlstad

Comment: Don't use  pow(10,i)  it is a floating point function and thus per definition imprecise. Just multiply an integer by 10 in each iteration of your loop;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is a floating point function and should **not** be used for integers.

It is also not required (from efficiency point of view) to recalculate the exponent from scratch every iteration. You can just keep a variable and multiply it by 10 in each one.

**You can try the code below:**

```
#include<iostream>

int toBinary(int num) 
{
    int ans = 0;
    int exp = 1;
    while (num)
    {
        int bit = num & 1;
        ans += bit * exp;
        // for next iteration:
        exp *= 10; 
        num /= 2;
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        std::cout << toBinary(i) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
10
...
10001
10010
10011
```

**Note** that the result will overflow pretty fast (2000 is already way to big for representing binary in an int the way you do).

**A side note:** [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).